# Simple way to share/stream my hardware microphone?

Tags: audio, streaming

I would like to share/stream my microphone in realtime so that I could listen this stream with any standard client like RTSP.

Interested in both Linux and FreeBSD solutions.

Solutions should be simple, i.e. it should not assume full scale RTSP service installation, which is able to do many things. For example, [simple-rtsp-server](https://github.com/aler9/rtsp-simple-server) is overcomplicated solution, because it allows to publish any external stream on the same server.

Comment: The simplest (and rawest) way on Linux would be to implement the dsnoop plugin (input mixer) as part of your alsa configuration file. https://alsa.opensrc.org/Dsnoop. At the time I quit FreeBSD, only OSS was supported, so such a solution using Alsa only would not work.

Comment: Can you provide more details please? dnsoop page shows how to save to wav only

Comment: Could you then please copy the output of arecord -L command as part of your question in order to check if the dsnoop plugin is not already implemented. (default on several so called "modern" distributions)

Comment: I mean, that's literally what VLC (video lan client) was invented for. Does the "streaming" dialog in VLC help you? If it does, you can simply copy&paste the options to `cvlc` if you need to work without GUI.